# Mostrar elemento al sobreponer cursor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy intentando que se muestre un elemento `div`al sobreponer el ratón sobre otro elemento, pero resulta que no hace nada. Y ya no sé que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Esto es lo que tengo en el documento `HTML`

```
<div id=""cancha>
  <div class="divDetalles">muestra </div>
  <div class="posicionJugador"></div>
</div>
```

Este es el código `CSS`

```
.divDetalles{
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Y esta es la función `Jquery`que maneja el evento. Tengo el evento dentro de la función porque así es como lo necesito.

```
function mostrarEliminarDetallesJugador(){
    $("#cancha").on('hover','.posicion_jugador',function(){

        var detalles = $(this).parent().find('.divDetalles');       

        $(this).mousemove(function(event){

            var x = event.clientX, y= event.clientY;

            $('.divDetalles').css('display','flex');
            detalles.css('top',(y+20)+"px");
            detalles.css('left',(x+20)+"px");
        });
    });
};
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Buen día, tu pregunta no está bien elaborada, que div está oculto? el mouse debe pasar sobre qué div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que deseas hacer, basta con usar el método [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerIn-handlerOut) de JQuery y escribir los manejadores de evento (`mouseenter` y `mouseleave`) adecuados.

El problema en tu código es que tiene mucho enredo con el llamado a clases padre y luego hijas de dicho padre:

```
var detalles = $(this).parent().find('.divDetalles');
```

Eso está un poco rebuscado, podrías simplemente usar:

```
$(event.currentTarget).find('.divDetalles').css(...);
```

Por otro lado, intentas usar el evento `hover`, el cual no existe para elementos del DOM. Tal vez tienes la confusión con la pseudo clase `:hover` de CSS.

Puedes consultar la [lista de eventos del Mouse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Mouse_events) en la documentación oficial.

Los eventos que te interesan son [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) y [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event).

JQuery nos provee de un método el cual recibe 2 manejadores como argumentos, uno para cada evento.

Tu código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
// Manejador para mouseenter
const showDetalles = (event) => {
  $(event.currentTarget).find('.divDetalles').css({
    "display": "flex", 
    "left": `${event.clientX + 20}px`,
    "top": `${event.clientY + 20}px`
  });
}

// manejador para mouseleave
const hideDetalles = (event) => {
  $(event.currentTarget).find('.divDetalles').css({"display": "none"});
}

$('#cancha').hover(showDetalles, hideDetalles);
```

```css
#cancha {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.divDetalles {
    display: none;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cancha">
  <div class="divDetalles">Oculto</div>
  <div class="posicionJugador">Visible</div>
</div>
```

Con esto ya tienes la funcionalidad que buscas.

En tu pregunta dices:

> Tengo el evento dentro de la función porque así es como lo necesito.

Pues envuelves el código en la función que creas conveniente, sin embargo, no lo veo práctico, ya que para que funcione debes ejecutar primero la función, por ejemplo, el `div` oculto no se mostrará si no presiono primero el botón:

```js
// Manejador para mouseenter
function miFuncion() {
  const showDetalles = (event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).find('.divDetalles').css({
      "display": "flex", 
      "left": `${event.clientX + 20}px`,
      "top": `${event.clientY + 20}px`
    });
  }

  // manejador para mouseleave
  const hideDetalles = (event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).find('.divDetalles').css({"display": "none"});
  }

  $('#cancha').hover(showDetalles, hideDetalles);
}

// aqui ejecuto la función si se presiona el botón
$('#ejecutar').click(e => {
  miFuncion();
});
```

```css
#cancha {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.divDetalles {
    display: none;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cancha">
  <div class="divDetalles">Oculto</div>
  <div class="posicionJugador">Visible</div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="ejecutar" type="button">Ejecutar Función</button>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.